# Using dynamic calls as criteria for a jpa call

Tags: java, database, jpa, entitymanager

In the following code we get the data from specific entity (Pet). Can I use this code to get
dynamically any entity (instead of pet use customer ,order etc)

```
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.where(cb.equal(pet.get("name"), "Fido"));
TypedQuery<Pet> q = em.createQuery(cq);
List<Pet> results = q.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course:

```
public <T> List<T> getEntitiesNamedFido(Class<T> clazz) {
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(clazz);
    Root<T> root = cq.from(clazz);
    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("name"), "Fido"));
    TypedQuery<T> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<T> results = q.getResultList();
}
```

Now pass any entity class having a persistent "name" property, and you'll get a list of the entity instances named Fido.

Answer (score 0):

Using templates on a function and passing the class type, argument names & values through arguments.